# I need help writing SQL Server trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, insert

I've made simplified [Entity Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGoXH.png) to show tables related to my question

I need an `AFTER INSERT` trigger on `Packings`.

I want it to update quantity in corresponding row of `dRoastedStocks` table for each coffee sort included in selected mix in `INSERTED` row of `Packings`.

Quantity should be calculated as:

```
"NewOne" = "OldOne" - "Capacity of selected package" * "Ratio of CoffeeSort in selected Mix" * "Number of packages"
```

Here, I've implemented it in C# using Entity Framework and it works perfectly, if somebody could make it into a SQL Server trigger, I would very much appreciate it

(`NewPacking` is referring to added row)

```
//For each CoffeeSort included into selected Mix
foreach (var mixDetail in NewPacking.Mix.Mix_Details)
{
    // Find row in dRoastedStocks which refers to CoffeeSort
    var roastedStock = _context.dRoastedStocks.First(x => x.CoffeeSort.Id == mixDetail.CoffeeSort.Id);
    // Update it's quantity with new value by substracting packed quantity
    // Packed quantity is calculated as "Capacity of selected package" * "Ratio of CoffeeSort in selected Mix" * "Number of packages"
    roastedStock.Quantity -= NewPacking.PackQuantity * mixDetail.Ratio/100 * NewPacking.Package.Capacity;
}
```

It's pretty complicated to explain, so I hope scheme helps a bit

EDIT: here's what I've tried to write in SQL, it's almost the same as C# I wrote previously

```
CREATE TRIGGER RoastedStocks_Insert_Packing
ON Packings
AFTER INSERT 
AS
    UPDATE dRoastedStocks
    SET dbo.dRoastedStocks.Quantity = 
          dbo.dRoastedStocks.Quantity - 
             (SELECT Ratio 
              FROM Mix_Details 
              WHERE Mix_Id = (SELECT INSERTED.Mix_Id FROM INSERTED)
                AND Mix_Details.CoffeeSort_Id = dRoastedStocks.CoffeeSort_Id) / 100
             * (SELECT INSERTED.PackQuantity FROM INSERTED)
             * (SELECT Capacity FROM Packages WHERE Id = (SELECT INSERTED.Package_Id FROM INSERTED))
```

Comment: Also, is it `MySQL` or `MS SQL Server` ?

Comment: @Squirrel It's SQL Server, sorry for inconvenience. And what do you mean what have I tried? I tried to write it in SQL and failed. I included code in question, but I don't think it will be of any use

Comment: please show us your trigger code.

Comment: @Squirrel I already did :)

Comment: So you're trying to keep a stock level up to date based on a trigger. It's normally better just to work this out on the fly afterwards (i.e. in a view), because if for some reason a trigger fails or someone manually updates your balance everything gets totally out of whack. Alternatively I suggest you create a stored procedure which does both operations in a transaction

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid thanks for advice, maybe I'll remake it in a stored procedure as you suggested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As many of published triggers here yours is also unaware of situation where many rows are inserted at once. All those subqueries would fail with "scalar...but many rows returned" error.

Have a look at this approach:

```
UPDATE rs SET
  Quantity -= md.Ratio / 100 * i.PackQuantity * pk.Capacity
FROM INSERTED i
INNER JOIN dbo.Mix_Details md
   ON md.Mix_Id = i.Mix_Id
INNER JOIN dbo.Packages pk
   ON pk.Id = i.Package_Id
INNER JOIN dbo.dRoastedStocks rs
   ON rs.CoffeeSort_Id = md.CoffeeSort_Id
```